# Need Dynamic S Box Library in Java

Tags: java, cryptography

I need a Java source code library that can dynamically generate the SBox ([substitution box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box)) for AES based on the AES256 key provided.

Comment: Please update the question to explain what `sbox` is.  Do you mean [substitution box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box)?

Comment: Yes, S Box is substitution box.